# How to create a functor as the sum of 2 functors?

Tags: c++, functor

Let's say I have 2 functors add and mult. `add2(x) = x+2` and `mult3(x) = 3x`. 
I want to create a combined tensor `t` such that `t(x) = x+2 + 3x`.
I came up with the solution of creating a *pair* functor, but I am not quite satisfied, as this solution does not scale to a higher number of functors.
What are my options?

```
struct add {
private:
    double c_;
public:
    add(double& c): c_(c) {}
    double operator()(double& x) {
        return c_ + x;
    }
};

struct mult {
private:
    double c_;
public:
    mult(double& c): c_(c) {}
    double operator()(double& x) {
        return c_ * x;
    }
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct pair {
private:
    T1 t1_;
    T2 t2_;
public:
    pair(T1 t1, T2 t2): t1_(t1), t2_(t2) {}
    double operator()(double& x) {
        return t1_(x) + t2_(x);
    }
}

add add2 = add(2);
mult mult3 = mult(3);
pair combined = pair(add2, mult3);
```

Comment: If you are using C++03 I don't see other options. BTW why do you take `double&` instead of `double`?

Comment: @kennytm copy constructor buddy

Comment: @IlayaRajaS What copy constructor? It is a plain `double`, not a generic `T` (even in that case it should take `const T&` not `T&`).

Comment: @kennytm sorry about that, i was talking about the add and mult. I was quite naive.

Comment: @IlayaRajaS OK :)

Comment: Can you use C++11 or C++14?

Comment: no reason for the double&, just made up the example like that! and I use c++11, but I'd be curious to have answer for c++14 as well :)

Answer (score 1):

The name `pair` doesn't really mean much about what the functor does. I think it make sense to create something along the following lines:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct plus
{
   plus(T1 t1, T2 t2) : t1_(t1), t2_(t2) {}
   double operator()(double x)
   {
      return t1_(x) + t2_(x);
   }
   T1 t1_;
   T2 t2_;
};
```

and provide a helper function to make an instance of such a type.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
plus<T1, T2> make_plus(T1 t1, T2 t2)
{
   return plus<T1, T2>(t1, t2);
}
```

Then, you can use:

```
add add2 = add(2);
mult mult3 = mult(3);
auto comb1 = make_plus(add2, mult3);
auto comb2 = make_plus(mult(10), make_plus(add2, mult3));
```

Here's a program that adds a `minus` for good measure.

```
#include <iostream>

struct add
{
   add(double c): c_(c) {}
   double operator()(double x) {
      return c_ + x;
   }
   double c_;
};

struct mult
{
   mult(double c): c_(c) {}
   double operator()(double x) {
      return c_ * x;
   }
   double c_;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct plus
{
   plus(T1 t1, T2 t2) : t1_(t1), t2_(t2) {}
   double operator()(double x)
   {
      return t1_(x) + t2_(x);
   }
   T1 t1_;
   T2 t2_;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
plus<T1, T2> make_plus(T1 t1, T2 t2)
{
   return plus<T1, T2>(t1, t2);
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct minus
{
   minus(T1 t1, T2 t2) : t1_(t1), t2_(t2) {}
   double operator()(double x)
   {
      return t1_(x) - t2_(x);
   }
   T1 t1_;
   T2 t2_;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
minus<T1, T2> make_minus(T1 t1, T2 t2)
{
   return minus<T1, T2>(t1, t2);
}


int main()
{
   add add2 = add(2);
   mult mult3 = mult(3);
   auto comb1 = make_plus(add2, mult3);
   auto comb2 = make_plus(mult(10), make_plus(add2, mult3));
   auto comb3 = make_minus(mult(10), make_plus(add2, mult3));

   std::cout << comb1(10) << std::endl;
   std::cout << comb2(10) << std::endl;
   std::cout << comb3(10) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
42
142
58
```

---

Another option will be to create types `add`, `mult`, `plus`, and `minus` in an application specific namespace and then add `operator+` and `operator-` overloads to make the code in `main` a bit more intuitive.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace myapp
{
   struct identity
   {
      double operator()(double x) { return x;}
   };

   struct add
   {
      add(double c): c_(c) {}
      double operator()(double x) {
         return c_ + x;
      }
      double c_;
   };

   struct mult
   {
      mult(double c): c_(c) {}
      double operator()(double x) {
         return c_ * x;
      }
      double c_;
   };

   template<typename T1, typename T2>
      struct plus
      {
         plus(T1 t1, T2 t2) : t1_(t1), t2_(t2) {}
         double operator()(double x)
         {
            return t1_(x) + t2_(x);
         }
         T1 t1_;
         T2 t2_;
      };

   template<typename T1, typename T2>
      plus<T1, T2> make_plus(T1 t1, T2 t2)
      {
         return plus<T1, T2>(t1, t2);
      }

   template<typename T1, typename T2>
      plus<T1, T2> operator+(T1 t1, T2 t2)
      {
         return make_plus(t1, t2);
      }

   template<typename T1, typename T2>
      struct minus
      {
         minus(T1 t1, T2 t2) : t1_(t1), t2_(t2) {}
         double operator()(double x)
         {
            return t1_(x) - t2_(x);
         }
         T1 t1_;
         T2 t2_;
      };

   template<typename T1, typename T2>
      minus<T1, T2> make_minus(T1 t1, T2 t2)
      {
         return minus<T1, T2>(t1, t2);
      }

   template<typename T1, typename T2>
      minus<T1, T2> operator-(T1 t1, T2 t2)
      {
         return make_minus(t1, t2);
      }
}

int main()
{
   using namespace myapp;
   add add2 = add(2);
   mult mult3 = mult(3);

   auto comb1 = add2 + mult3;
   auto comb2 = mult(10) +  add2 + mult3;
   auto comb3 = mult(10) - (add2 + mult3);
   auto comb4 = identity{} + add(25);

   std::cout << comb1(10) << std::endl;
   std::cout << comb2(10) << std::endl;
   std::cout << comb3(10) << std::endl;
   std::cout << comb4(10) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I like the idea of defining the + operator!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fairly concise solution using polymorphic lambdas (C++14 required). To keep it short, this example uses named functions and supports only one function argument. However, it would be fairly easy to extend this approach to support multiple arguments and a more natural calling syntax using operator overloading.

[*Demo on Wandbox*](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/FupqHtskNWTfMtpY)

```
#include <type_traits>

struct arg_t {};

auto eval(auto const& x, arg_t) {
  return x;
}

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, int> = 0>
auto eval(auto const&, T const& t) {
  return t;
}

template <typename F, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_arithmetic<F>::value, int> = 0>
auto eval(auto const& x, F const& f) {
  return f(x);
}

auto binary(auto const& a, auto const& b, auto const& f) {
  return [a, b, f](auto const& v) { return f(eval(v, a), eval(v, b)); };
}

auto sum(auto const& a, auto const& b) {
  return binary(a, b, [](auto const& a, auto const& b) { return a + b; });
}

auto product(auto const& a, auto const& b) {
  return binary(a, b, [](auto const& a, auto const& b) { return a * b; });
}
```

Then call like so:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  arg_t x;
  auto f = sum(sum(x, 2), product(3, x));
  std::cout << f(4) << "\n";
}
```